# Realm and Reactive Cocoa

Tags: mvvm, realm, reactive-cocoa

I am using `Realm` 2.0.4 and `ReactiveCococa` 2.5 (Objective-C API)

I am trying to use MVVM.

I am trying to "bind" my VM to an underlying `RLMObject`. Which I have done with some success. Like this.

```
RACSignal *invalidationSignal = [[[RACObserve(self, boundedProfile.invalidated)
                                   takeUntil:self.rac_willDeallocSignal]
                                  filter:^BOOL (NSNumber *invalid) {
                                      return [invalid boolValue] == true; // We're only interested in the cases where it was invalidated.
                                  }]
                                 replayLast]; // For multicasting the same value for all subscribers.
@weakify(self);
self.updateSignalDisposable = [[RACObserve(self, boundedProfile.currentProfileTimestamp)
                                takeUntil:invalidationSignal]
                               subscribeNext:^(id x) {
                                   @strongify(self)
                                   CYRLMProfile * profile    = [CYRLMProfile profileWithID:self.userId];
                                   self.userId               = profile.userId;
                                    ...
                               }];
```

My problem here is that when my VM gets dealloc'ed, I set `nil` to my realm object, and that also deallocates the `realm` associated with the bounded object.

Some times this happens when Realm is in the middle of a write transaction.  and it crashes because it's canceling a write transaction on a different thread of the thread where it was running.

*EDIT:*

To expand on the issue:
- I have a ViewModel with a strong reference to a RealmObject
- That RealmObject was retrieved from a Realm from any thread
- When the ViewModel is deallocated:
    - the RealmObject is nilled leading it to be deallocated since it was the only strong reference to it
    - that in turn leads to that object's RLMRealm being released because it was the remaining strong reference to that realm
    - when deallocating the realm checks if it is in a write transaction and if so tries to cancel it, leading to the crash on incorrect thread

I think that if I remove the RAC observation the issue still happens.
I am able to reproduce this forceably, by creating a viewmodel with a realm object in a thread other than main and call beginWriteTranscaction and then nilling that object in the main thread, leading to its deallocation
The code is something like this:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_LOW, 0), ^{

    RLMRealm *realm = [RLMRealm defaultRealm];
    CYRLMProfile *profile = [CYRLMProfile profileWithId:10 inRealm:realm];
    __block ViewModel *vm = [ViewModel viewModelWithProfile:profile];

    [realm beginWriteTransaction];

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

        vm = nil;
    });
});
```

Comment: Could you share an error message you get, stacktrace etc. Also make sure you initialize a new instance of Realm for each thread in your app, see more info in Threading section in docs: https://realm.io/docs/objc/latest/#threading

Comment: The message is "Realm accessed from incorrect thread" and here is the stacktrace: http://pastebin.com/s0GKVjwq

Answer (score 0):

`Realm accessed from incorrect thread` means that you tried to access realm instance created on another thread. As I suggested in a comment above, make sure you initialize a new instance of Realm for each thread and get a new instance of your object from that Realm instance.

> The only thing you have to be aware of is that you cannot have multiple threads sharing the same instances of Realm objects. If multiple threads need to access the same objects they will each need to get their own instances

See more at https://realm.io/docs/objc/latest/#threading.

Comment: The problem here is that I am binding the object in a thread (and I wasn't being cautions on which thread the object was bing bound). But all dealloc's happened in the main thread. I am not trying to access the object itself, just deallocating it. Should a dealloc of a Realm Object occur on the same thread it was created?

Comment: In the case of `RACObserve` (which is KVO), events are delivered on the same thread where the change was made. Do you call `RACObserver` on the main thread?

Comment: I wasn't forcing `RACObserve` to be called on the main thread. But I can do that. But I get that it should be called on the main thread in order to prevent Inconsistent thread when dealloc'ing. Is that what it should be done? Honestly I just wanted some validation if my approach was "correct", or if there was a better way to achieve this.

Comment: I've just realized that you use only `invalidated` property in your example, that property actually could be accessed from any thread. Do you access realm objects or realm somewhere else in you code? Are you able to reproduce this issue constantly?

Comment: Sorry for the delay, i've added more info on this.

Comment: I'm not sure I've understood your code sample correctly. Could you share an example project that reproduces your issue? Why do you start write transaction here?

Comment: that sample code seems to be only for reproducing the issue he has, not the actual app code he uses